# Tensorflow loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00

Tags: deep-learning, keras, nlp, tensorflow, python-3.x

I was making changes to improve myself in a chatbot code using LSTM. But Loss and truth values are getting ridiculous values.
[image]

Code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from pandas import read_csv

from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, LSTM, Embedding ,Dropout
from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.layers import CuDNNGRU
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

mark_start = "ssss "
mark_end = " eeee"
data_src=[]
data_dest=[]

df = read_csv('Conversation.csv')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    soru = row['question']
    cevap = row['answer']
    cevap = mark_start + cevap + mark_end
    data_src.append(soru)
    data_dest.append(cevap)

class TokenizerWrap(Tokenizer):
    def __init__(self,texts, padding, reverse=False,num_words=None):
        Tokenizer.__init__(self, num_words=num_words)
        self.fit_on_texts(texts)
        self.index_to_word=dict(zip(self.word_index.values(), self.word_index.keys()))
        self.tokens=self.texts_to_sequences(texts)
        if reverse:
            self.tokens = [list(reversed(x)) for x in self.tokens]
            truncating="pre"
        else:
            truncating="post"

        self.num_tokens=[len(x) for x in self.tokens]
        self.max_tokens=int(np.mean(self.num_tokens)+2*np.std(self.num_tokens))
        self.tokens_padded=pad_sequences(self.tokens,maxlen=self.max_tokens,padding=padding,truncating=truncating)
    def token_to_word(self,token):
        word = ' ' if token==0 else self.index_to_word[token]
        return word
    def tokens_to_string(self,tokens):
        words = [self.index_to_word[token] for token in tokens if token!=0]
        text = ' '.join(words)
        return text
    def text_to_tokens(self,text,padding,reverse=False):
        tokens = self.texts_to_sequences([text])
        tokens = np.array(tokens)
        if reverse:
            tokens = np.flip(tokens,axis=1)
            truncating='pre'
        else:
            truncating='post'
        tokens=pad_sequences(tokens,maxlen=self.max_tokens,padding=padding,truncating=truncating)
        return tokens

tokenizer = TokenizerWrap(texts=data_src + data_dest,padding='pre')
VOCAB_SIZE = len(tokenizer.word_index)+1

from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from re import sub

vocab = []
for word in tokenizer.word_index:
    vocab.append(word)
    
def tokenize(sentences):
    tokens_list = []
    vocabulary = []
    for sentence in sentences:
        sentence = sentence.lower()
        sentence = sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', sentence)
        tokens = sentence.split()
        vocabulary += tokens
        tokens_list.append(tokens)
    return tokens_list , vocabulary

# encoder_input_data
tokenlenmis_sorular = tokenizer.text_to_tokens(data_src,"post")
maxlen_questions = max([len(x) for x in tokenlenmis_sorular])
encoder_input_data = tokenlenmis_sorular
data_src

print(encoder_input_data.shape)

# decoder_input_data
tokenlenmis_cevaplar = tokenizer.text_to_tokens(data_dest,"post")
maxlen_answers = max([len(x) for x in tokenlenmis_cevaplar])
decoder_input_data = tokenlenmis_cevaplar

print(decoder_input_data.shape)

tokenlenmis_cevaplar = tokenizer.text_to_tokens(data_dest, "post")
#padded_answers = pad_sequences(tokenlenmis_cevaplar, maxlen=maxlen_answers, padding='post', truncating='post')
onehot_answers = to_categorical(tokenlenmis_cevaplar, VOCAB_SIZE)
decoder_output_data = np.array(onehot_answers)

print(decoder_output_data.shape)


print(decoder_output_data.shape)
encoder_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(maxlen_questions ,))
encoder_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(VOCAB_SIZE, 200 , mask_zero=True) (encoder_inputs)
encoder_outputs , state_h , state_c = LSTM(200 , return_state=True)(encoder_embedding)
encoder_states = [ state_h , state_c ]

decoder_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(maxlen_answers , ))
decoder_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(VOCAB_SIZE, 200 , mask_zero=True) (decoder_inputs)
decoder_lstm = LSTM(200 , return_state=True , return_sequences=True)
decoder_outputs , _ , _ = decoder_lstm (decoder_embedding , initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(VOCAB_SIZE , activation=tf.keras.activations.softmax) 
output = decoder_dense (decoder_outputs)

model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], output)
model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(learning_rate = 0.003), loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=["accuracy"])

model.summary()

model.fit([encoder_input_data , decoder_input_data], decoder_output_data, batch_size=512, epochs=200)
def inference():
    
    encoder_model = tf.keras.models.Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_states)
    
    decoder_state_input_h = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(200 ,))
    decoder_state_input_c = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(200 ,))
    
    decoder_states_inputs = [decoder_state_input_h, decoder_state_input_c]
    
    decoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = decoder_lstm(decoder_embedding , initial_state=decoder_states_inputs)
    decoder_states = [state_h, state_c]
    decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)
    decoder_model = tf.keras.models.Model([decoder_inputs] + decoder_states_inputs,[decoder_outputs] + decoder_states)
    
    return encoder_model , decoder_model

def preprocess_input(input_sentence):
    tokens = input_sentence.lower().split()
    tokens_list = []
    for word in tokens:
        tokens_list.append(tokenizer.word_index[word]) 
    return pad_sequences([tokens_list] , maxlen=maxlen_questions , padding='post')


enc_model , dec_model = inference()

tests = ['Hello', 'Are you a', 'What is your name', 'That is a very long name', 'see you later']
print()
for i in range(5):
    states_values = enc_model.predict(preprocess_input(tests[i]))
    empty_target_seq = np.zeros((1 , 1))
    empty_target_seq[0, 0] = tokenizer.word_index['start']
    stop_condition = False
    decoded_translation = ''
    
    while not stop_condition :
        dec_outputs , h , c = dec_model.predict([empty_target_seq] + states_values)
        sampled_word_index = np.argmax(dec_outputs[0, -1, :])
        sampled_word = None
        
        for word , index in tokenizer.word_index.items() :
            if sampled_word_index == index :
                decoded_translation += f' {word}'
                sampled_word = word
        
        if sampled_word == 'end' or len(decoded_translation.split()) > maxlen_answers:
            stop_condition = True
            
        empty_target_seq = np.zeros((1 , 1))  
        empty_target_seq[0 , 0] = sampled_word_index
        states_values = [h , c] 
    print(f'You: {tests[i]}')
    print()
    decoded_translation = decoded_translation.split(' end')[0]
    print(f'Bot: {decoded_translation}')
    print('-'*25)
```

Thank you in advance.